# domain name on bitrix virtual appliance running on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012, bitrix

though am really new to bitrix24, i have been trying to do some customization based on the tutorials i saw on their site. I have setup a self hosted version using the centOS VA with VMWare which is running on a windows server 2012 r2. but i am having a challenge with the domain name resolution. as it is the site can be accessed in the local network via the static IP i assigned it in the VM, but i am trying to map the IP to a name and i have not been successful. I checked some videos on youtube on DNS configuration for windows sever 2012 and carried out the instructions but still have not been able to resolve the IP to the name because after i have done it, when i type the name on another workstation on the local network it does not work. please i would be most gratefull if anyone here can point me in the right direction. Thank you all

Comment: Do you use bitrixVM?

Comment: yes i used bitrix vm (VMware Edition v 7.0.1)